# How to fix "AVDRegister - AppleAVDCheckPlatform() returned FALSE"

Tags: ios, objective-c, hevc

I use this code to check if my iphone support hevc hard decode

```
BOOL hardwareDecodeSupported = VTIsHardwareDecodeSupported(kCMVideoCodecType_HEVC);
```

but on console I got a warning:
"AVDRegister - AppleAVDCheckPlatform() returned FALSE" and the hardwareDecodeSupported property is true. 
my device is iPhone7 with iOS11.3.1