# AVDRegister - AppleAVDCheckPlatform() returned FALSE

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an `imagePickerController` that selects videos and then passes through a function to split the video.

My problem is it prints `AVDRegister - AppleAVDCheckPlatform() returned FALSE` the first time I run it and the table view is empty, no errors. But the second time i run the code works fine
The same question hasn't been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193908/how-to-fix-avdregister-appleavdcheckplatform-returned-false)

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? NSURL
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("VIDEO URL : ", videoURL!)

    // gets duration of video in seconds
    let asset = AVAsset(url: videoURL! as URL)
    let length = Float(asset.duration.value) / Float(asset.duration.timescale)
    print("video length: \(length) seconds")
    lengthOfVid = length
    numOfRows =  Int(ceil(lengthOfVid / Float(duration!)))

    //alert dialog if length of video is > 15 mins i.e 900s
    if length > 900 {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("alertTitle", comment: "alertTitle"),
                                      message: NSLocalizedString("alertMessage", comment: "alertMessage"),
                                      preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("alertCancel", comment: "alertCancel"), style: .cancel))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        //run on background thread
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            self.trimingVideo(videoURL: self.videoURL!, repititions: self.numOfRows)

        }
    }
}
```